# Custom search webpart in sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I wish to create a custom search webpart using visual studio 2010 using c#. The search must be able to search for all users, document libraries, list, etc in my sharepoint and display the results. How should I go about creating it. I searched various sites, and I am unable to find a good source for creating a custom web part that I can deploy onto my sharepoint 2010.

Please assist. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To develop a custom webpart for search, You can follow the post here :

http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2011/10/28/sharepoint-keywordquery/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.